# Interpolate.splrep returning "nans"

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate a simple function with a cubic spline using scipy. I have instructions to use a 0.0001 space grid (thus the design of *v*) and to use 5 evenly spaced knots.

```
def h(x):
    if -2 < x < 0:
        return (x+0.5)**2
    elif 0 < x < 2:
        return (x-0.5)**2

h = np.vectorize(h)

v = np.linspace(-2,2,num=40000)
knots = np.linspace(-1.999, 1.9999, 5)
tck_h = interpolate.splrep(v, h(v), t=knots)
result_ip_h = interpolate.splev(v, tck_h)
```

However, tck (the tuple that is returned by interpolate.splrep) seems to be returning both more knots (some repeated) and several "nans" for coefficients:

```
(array([-2.000000e+00, -2.000000e+00, -2.000000e+00, -2.000000e+00,
        -1.999000e+00, -9.992750e-01,  4.500000e-04,  1.000175e+00,
         1.999900e+00,  2.000000e+00,  2.000000e+00,  2.000000e+00,
         2.000000e+00]),
 array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]),
 3)
```

I thought maybe 40000 points at x was too much but reducing that wasn't a problem. Maybe it's a problem with the function h?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the implementation of the `h` function. The problem seems to be that the function was not defined everywhere, therefore returning NaN values (actually None values)...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate

def h(x):
    if x < 0:
        return (x+0.5)**2
    else:
        return (x-0.5)**2

h = np.vectorize(h)

v = np.linspace(-2, 2, num=500)


knots = np.linspace(-1.999, 1.999, 5)
tck_h = interpolate.splrep(v, h(v), t=knots)
result_ip_h = interpolate.splev(v, tck_h)

plt.plot(v, h(v), label='h');
plt.plot(v, result_ip_h, label='spline'); plt.legend();
```